# execute python script from cron don't send mail

Tags: python-3.x, cron, raspberry-pi

I've script in python that takes photos from raspberry camera and send mail with this photos. From command line everything works OK, script start do the jobs and finishes without errors.

I setup cron to execute script every 1 hour. 
Every hour I get mail but without attachments.
Where or how can I check why script executed from cron don't send attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While running cron job check any relative paths is given in your code, then either change it to absolute path or change the directory inside the script. Then only the cron job will take the attachment or anything that need to include into your script.